# Read variable from file

Tags: python, file, powershell

I need to read a Python file in PowerShell. The problem I am not able to use `Import-Csv` here as some info is available before each section.

I need to read the `Machine_List` and fetch the IP address of machine present in the list.

```py
#machine1 details sample
machine_1 = {
              "ip" : "192.168.x.xxx",
              "username" : "abc",
              "password" : "xyz"
            }
#machine_2 details sample
machine_2 = {
              "ip" : "192.168.x.xxx",
              "username" : "abc",
              "password" : "xyz"
            }
#machine_3 details sample
machine_3 = {
              "ip" : "192.168.x.xxx",
              "username" : "abc",
              "password" : "xyz"
            }
#machine_list details sample
MACHINE_LIST = [
                 machine_1,
                 machine_2
               ]
```

I am able to read the entire file into not able to extract the value for the variable.

```psh
# Read machine and the associated IP address
# Turn off restricted mode (Pre-req for powershell execution)
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$machine_list = Get-Content "C:\\machine_list.py"
Foreach-Object ($line in machine_list)
{
    Write-Host $line
}
```

I also tried this, but its not working

```psh
Get-Content "C:\\machine_list.py" | Foreach-Object {
    $var = $_.Split('=')
    New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
}
```

Can any one guide me through this implementation?

Comment: have you tried reading it from a `.txt` instead of a `.py`?

Comment: The file which I need to read is in .py. Hence, I have not tried with .txt

Comment: So you are trying to run a Python Script in a powershell script?

Comment: No.. I am trying to read a python file content using PowerShell..

Comment: Out of curiosity: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file contains Python statements spanning multiple lines, so simply reading the file line by line and splitting it at `=` characters won't work. A little regular expression magic should do what you want, though:

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:\machine_list.py' -Raw

$re = '(?ms)(\w+)\s*=\s*\{\s*"ip"\s*:\s*"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"'

$txt | Select-String -Pattern $re -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object {
    $var = $_.Groups | Select-Object -Skip 1 -Expand Value
    New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
  }
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `(?ms)` allows the regular expression to cover multiple lines.
- `(\w+)` matches a sequence of one or more character, number or underscore. The parentheses group the match, so that it can later be referenced as a separate entity.
- `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)` matches an IP address. Again, the match is grouped, so that it can later be referenced.
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.
- `\{` matches a literal opening curly bracket (escaping is required, because curly brackets are special characters in regular expressions.

Note that prior to PowerShell v3 the parameter `-Raw` isn't available. In that case you need to replace `Get-Content 'C:\machine_list.py' -Raw` with `Get-Content 'C:\machine_list.py' | Out-String`.

Also, it might be a good idea to collect the addresses in a hashtable rather than creating individual variables.

```
$machineNames = @{}
$txt | ... |
  ForEach-Object {
    $var = $_.Groups | Select-Object -Skip 1 -Expand Value
    $machineNames[$var[0]] = $var[1]
  }
```

To extract the variable `MACHINE_LIST` you need a different expression, though, since that's a different type of data structure.

```
$re2 = '(?ms)machine_list\s*=\s*\[\s*(\w+(?:,\s*\w+)*)\s*\]'

$txt | Select-String -Pattern $re2 |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object {
    $machineList = $_.Groups[1].Value -split ',\s*'
  }
```

Then you can get the IP addresses from the hashtable like this:

```
$machineList | ForEach-Object { $machineNames[$_] }
```

Comment: I am getting "Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null." error, is this related to regular expression?
`Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
+ $machineList | ForEach-Object { $machineNames[ <<<< $_] }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex`

Comment: @Yougandhara Did you create and populate the hashtable first?

Comment: Yes, but the .py file I am reading is slightly different that the given one.. I will try out regular expression with the help of your answer..

Comment: If the input is different from what you said you need to adjust the regular expression(s) accordingly.

Comment: I tried the same input file and your exact similar code.. but its not printing the ip values from hashtable?

Comment: @Yougandhara It worked just fine when I tested it. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87541/discussion-between-yougandhara-and-ansgar-wiechers).